# Запуск js скрипта в blazor приложении

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Имеется приложение с использованием blazor.
Суть в том, что выбираю курс и группу и затем нажимаю на кнопку и выводится список div'ов с информацией.
Хочу после нажатия на кнопку запускать скрипт, который спозиционирует меня на определённом дне (т.е. проскролит до него).

Если ставлю вызов скрипта на отдельную кнопку, на событие onclick, то скрипт нормально срабатывает, но мне нужно чтобы он автоматически срабатывал, после прогрузки списка div'ов.

Я пробовал вызывать на onloadend, но что-то не выходит, либо я это делаю не правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет подход, описанный в 
https://github.com/DevExpress/Blazor/tree/master/tools/DevExpress.Blazor.AnchorUtils

То есть, вы пишете JS для скрола и вызываете его в коде, например в OnAfterRender

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)